# DataGridView inserting new row when filling column headers

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

DataGridView inserting an extra row every time I populate with data. The row appears even if I only fill the column headers. This is causing problems when I try to get values of each cell.

Is there a way to avoid this perhaps in properties?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean but it seems unlikely that it would be a feature of the DGV to add extra rows for no good reason, so it's more likely that your code is doing it so I suggest adding the relevant snippets of code to your question.

Comment: It seems like AllowUserToAddRows property that adding new row even if i populate the column only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't very clear what your exact issue is.

The only behaviour I can think of that matches what you are describing is the `AllowUserToAddRows` property of the `DataGridView`. This provides a row at the bottom of the grid populated with empty, editable controls.

If you set the property to false, do you get the behaviour that you want?

Another option is to ignore this row when doing any other processing - the new row will have the property of `IsNewRow` set to true:

```
if (!dataGridView1.Row[i].IsNewRow)
{ 
    //This is not the new row
}
```

(Sorry about the C# above - my vb.Net is very rusty at the moment)